# Convert a Date/Time string to 8 hours ahead Date/Time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to be able to convert the following date and time string to from Pacific date/time to 8 hours ahead from time (next day's date if goes into next day)

Here is what I need to add to:

```sql
CONVERT(varchar(10), dbo.S85_CALENDAR_SCHEDULES.cals_date,101) + ' ' + 
LEFT(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(26), dbo.S85_CALENDAR_SCHEDULES.cals_start_time,109), 14),5) + ' ' +
RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(26), dbo.S85_CALENDAR_SCHEDULES.cals_start_time,109), 2) AS DATE_AND_START_TIME
```

So I need     08/07/2023  1:00 PM
to return as  08/07/2023  9:00 PM

and I need    08/07/2023  8:00 PM
to return as  08/08/2023  4:00 AM

Comment: Neither of those times are pacific or GMT times, they have no offset details. To be able to change a date and time from one timezone to another the value you are changing *need* offset data.

Comment: Is `08/07` August 7th or July 8th? Please don't use ambiguous date formats because some of your audience is _definitely_ using different regional settings than you are. And clarify: are all date/time values in that column stored as Pacific time? Do they all observe DST correctly?

Comment: Dates aren't strings and have no format. String manipulations will only cause bugs or worse, bad data. What is the *real* type of `cals_start_time`? Is it already a `datetime` perhaps? T-SQL has functions that can convert actual date values (not strings) from one *offset* to another. There's also the [AT TIME ZONE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/at-time-zone-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) clause that can convert a date to a different timezone, returning a `datetimeoffset` value

Comment: Pacific Time which is USA as in August 7, 2023

Comment: `which is USA` - sure, but just because the date/time is in an American timezone doesn't mean the person working with it is American. Don't make people guess.

Comment: Also Pacific time isn't always 8 hours different to GMT. *If* you mean Pacific time to GMT (UTC+00:00) then Pacific time can be 8 or 7 hours different depending if it's PST(UTC - 08:00) or PDT (UTC-07:00).

Comment: @KLR is it? Do the Australians agree? `Pacific time` is an ambiguous name. Three letter acronyms like PDT are *also* ambiguous (IST can be Irish, Israel, or India) but at least not *that* ambiguous

Comment: You really, really need to post the table definition *and* explain what the column contains. Unless it's `datetimeoffset`, you have to make assumptions what the timezone is.

Comment: I *hope* by GMT you do mean UTC too, and not "UK Time" (which would be GMT in the winter and BST in the summer).

Comment: I am really sorry I asked this question - I don't even understand 'need offset data'.  I'm a visual person unfortunately.  Forget I even asked a question.  I feel like I'm being attacked here for not knowing!

Comment: There's an  [AT TIME ZONE example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/at-time-zone-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#b-convert-values-between-different-time-zones) that shows how to make the timezone explicit and convert, even with a `datetime`, with `cals_start_time AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'`. `AT TIME ZONE` uses Windows timezone names. The first specifies that the `datetime` value is at PST. The second converts it to UTC

Comment: *"I don't even understand 'need offset data'"* A time with an Offset. For example `2023-08-07T17:14:27+01:00`; these are stored using `datetimeoffset`.

Comment: In the summertime, [GMT/UTC are only _seven_ hours ahead of Pacific Time](https://dbfiddle.uk/mmgXZ2ZX). Nobody's attacking you but we can't give the right answer if we don't know the problem or if the answer you expect is even correct.

Comment: @KLR you aren't being attacked, nor does this have to do with being a visual person. You're asking how to convert times between timezones. But you say you don't understand timezones. At the very least post the table definitions so people can explain this to you

Comment: @KLR, you are not being attacked. Your more experienced peers are trying to educate you on datetime fundamentals in SQL world.

Comment: If `cals_start_time` is a `datetime` storing local time in the PST timezone, you need to use `cals_start_time AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'` If it's a `datetimeoffset` you only need `cals_start_time AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'` because the value already contains the timezone offset.

Comment: well it looks like I left off the first line off!! 
 convert(varchar(10), dbo.S85_CALENDAR_SCHEDULES.cals_date,101) + ' ' + LEFT(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(26), dbo.S85_CALENDAR_SCHEDULES.cals_start_time,109), 14),5) + ' ' +
  RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(26), dbo.S85_CALENDAR_SCHEDULES.cals_start_time,109), 2) AS DATE_AND_START_TIME
So I had a date and time - separately they print as this:
date - 2023-08-07 00:00:00.000
time - 1900-01-01 16:00:00.000
That I was trying to get as 8 hours ahead as '08/08/2023 4:00 AM'.
Hopefully that makes more sense?  Sorry I messed up in original post - forgive me

Comment: The OP is *not* being attacked, @TomBoyd . Everything above is to educate the user as well as help us understand the user's requirements, which, unfortunately, aren't clear at this point.

Comment: How is he not being attacked @Thom A? He asked how to do datetime + 8hrs and it turned into GMT vs UTC vs PST vs DST. He replies that it's USA pacific time and gets questioned whether the user is American? How is that in any way relevant? The convert in the example is concerning but why is there anything in this thread about Australia? I agree some good points are being made but it's overshadowed by passive aggressive responses of little value. Of note is the OP has apologized for posting the question. You may not think so but it's pretty obvious the op feels attacked.

Comment: Feeling attacked and being attacked aren't the same thing, @TomBoyd . The OP stated they felt attacked, and no one has disputed that, but there wasn't actually any attacking. We, as experts, needed to further information and to explain why the problem the OP proposed is far from simple as they think it is.

Comment: @TomBoyd Should I feel attacked for being told my "panties" are "in a wad"? I don't. Nobody was attacking anyone, but being hyperbolic for effect certainly doesn't help anything. Why do you think whether they mean GMT or UTC is irrelevant? Or whether the date is included with DST or not? They think Pacific time is 8 hours behind GMT, which it's not in the summer, so obviously there is some clarification needed. If you consider asking for that clarification "attacking" - or think being sexist is cool - then maybe online isn't a safe place for you.

Comment: I am REALLY close - thanks all for your help - the AT TIME ZONE really helped me out  cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),dbo.S85_CALENDAR_SCHEDULES.cals_date,101) + ' ' + 
dbo.S85_CALENDAR_SCHEDULES.cals_start_time AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time' AT TIME ZONE 'GMT Standard Time'  as datetime)

  2023-08-07 21:00:00.000

I may not be able to get it to a desired 08/07/2023 9:00 PM but your help as been greatly appreciated.  Sorry for all the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Working with strings when handling datetime / date / time makes maybe shorter code though placing extra stress due to implicit conversion work on the query engine.

Fair bit of warning: The following code shows a lot more and some real understanding of ISO 8601 is useful but not necessary. Also the code falls short of using datetimeoffset which is a better alternative when handling time zones. More at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetimeoffset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Code will generate a table with a date and time column as shown in the question. Assumed that base data is ignorant about time zones.

First part shows work necessary to combine these two columns into a single datetime2 type by adding number of seconds of the time column to date column (which needs conversion to type to hold time values first).

Last part then combines this with a time offset. Using this approach the query can later be easily amended to allow different time zones. In the example time zone is hard-coded and joined with "PT".

```
DECLARE
  @TimeTableEntry
  TABLE
(
  Dated   date
, Timed   time
)
;
INSERT INTO
  @TimeTableEntry
VALUES
  ( Convert( date, '2023-07-08', 120 ), Convert( time, '01:00:00 PM', 120 ) )
, ( Convert( date, '2023-08-07', 120 ), Convert( time, '10:00:00 PM', 120 ) )
;
SELECT
  Dated
, Timed
, Convert( datetime2(0), Dated ) AS DatedConvertedToDatetime2
, Convert( datetime2(0), Timed ) AS TimedConvertedToDatetime2
, Datediff( ss, Convert(datetime2(0), '1900-01-01', 120 ), Convert( datetime2(0), Timed ) ) AS SecondsDiff
, DateAdd( ss
  , Datediff( ss, Convert(datetime2(0), '1900-01-01', 120 ), Convert( datetime2(0), Timed ) )
  , Convert( datetime2(0), Dated ) ) AS Datetimed
FROM
  @TimeTableEntry
;
WITH
  cteTimeOffset
(
  TimeZone
, HourOffset
)
AS
(
  SELECT 
    Cast( 'PT' AS varchar(3) ) AS TimeZone
  , Cast( 8 AS tinyint ) AS TimeOffset
)
, cteDatetimeConversion
(
  DateOriginal
, TimeOriginal
, Datetime2Converted
, Datetime2Offset
)
AS
(
  SELECT
    Dated
  , Timed
  , DateAdd( ss
      , Datediff( ss, Convert(datetime2(0), '1900-01-01', 120 ), Convert( datetime2(0), tte.Timed ) )
      , Convert( datetime2(0), tte.Dated ) 
    ) AS Datetime2Converted
  , DateAdd( hh, cto.HourOffset, 
      DateAdd( ss
      , Datediff( ss, Convert(datetime2(0), '1900-01-01', 120 ), Convert( datetime2(0), tte.Timed ) )
      , Convert( datetime2(0), tte.Dated ) ) 
    ) AS Datetime2Offset
  FROM
    @TimeTableEntry AS tte
    INNER JOIN cteTimeOffset AS cto
      ON  cto.TimeZone = 'PT'
)
SELECT
  cdc.DateOriginal
, cdc.TimeOriginal
, cdc.Datetime2Converted
, cdc.Datetime2Offset
FROM
  cteDatetimeConversion AS cdc
;
```

Converting a date to a special format is best done with the FORMAT function -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16. Very capable of handling regional display requirements.

As final word: When handling and talking about dates and times ISO 8601 is your real friend. It is no wonder that most database engines use this standard for default display.